# Помогите исправить ошибку в программе. Сам не могу

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

const int nstr=6, nstb=9;
int b[nstr][nstb];

int i, j;
int d = 0;

srand(time(NULL));
cout << "Иссходный массив:\n";
for (int k = 0; k < nstr; k++) {
    for (int f = 0; f < nstb; f++){
        b[k][f] = rand() % 10 - 1;
        cout << b[k][f] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}   // Заполнение массива

do {
    cout << "Введите i:\n";
    cin >> i;
    i++;
} while (i > nstb);
do {
    cout << "Введите j:\n";
    cin >> j;
    j++;
} while (j > nstr); //Ввод i и j и проверка на выход за рамки
// РАБОЧЕЕ

d = b[i][j];
cout << d;

if (i >= nstb) {
    for (int k = i; k <= nstr; k++) {
        for (int f = i; f <= nstr; k++) { 
            b[i][j] += b[k][f];
        }
    }
}
else {
    if (i < j) {
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            for (int f = i; f <= j; k++) {
                int d = 0;
                b[i][j] += b[k][f];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int k = j; k <= i; k++) {
            for (int f = j; f <= i; k++) {
                int d = 0;
                b[i][j] += b[k][f];
            }
        }
    }
}
b[i][j] = b[i][j] - d;
cout << b[i][j] << "\n";

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x007E6449 в 677g.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00BF4020.
В строке
b[i][j] += b[k][f];

Comment: Почему во всех циклах инкрементится `k++`?

Comment: Так `i` - это строка а не столбец. А Вы сравниваете в цикле `i > nstb`, хотя по логике должно быть `nstr`. В цикле с `j` аналогичная проблема

Comment: наверно потому что мы используем k как номер переменной?
в последнем ошибку увидел, спасибо

Comment: @EOF спасибо помогло.